# Picker buttons do not show up

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to add "done" and "cancel" buttons in a toolbar above a pickerView that will be used to change the value of a label. The label should only be changed when "done" is clicked not when UIPicker received rowSelected.

I can't understand why my "done" and "cancel" buttons do not show above my picker? I'm sure this will be marked as duplicate, but I've done something very similar in Swift 4, and this doesn't seem to work in Swift 5.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var freq: UILabel!
    var freqOptions = ["Hz", "kHz", "MHz"]
    var freqPicker = UIPickerView()
    @IBOutlet weak var freqTextField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        freqPicker = UIPickerView( frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 216) )
        freqPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        freqPicker.delegate = self
        freqPicker.dataSource = self
        freqPicker.isHidden = true
        let toolBar    = UIToolbar()
        let cancelItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Cancel",
            style: .plain,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(cancelFreqInput)
        )
        let middleItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let doneItem   = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Done",
            style: .done,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(confirmFreqInput)
        )
        toolBar.setItems( [cancelItem, middleItem, doneItem], animated : false )
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        view.addSubview(freqPicker)
        let freqTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(freqTap(gestureReconizer:)))
        freq.addGestureRecognizer(freqTap)
        freqTextField.inputView = freqPicker
        freqTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        freqTextField.isHidden = true
        freq.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    @objc func cancelFreqInput() {
        freqTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        freq.text = "Hz"
        freqTextField.isHidden = true
    }
    
    @objc func confirmFreqInput() {
        freqTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        freqTextField.isHidden = true
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return freqOptions.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        freq.text = freqOptions[row]
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return freqOptions[row]
    }

    @objc func freqTap(gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        freqPicker.isHidden = false
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to add a picker as a subview. You just need to set it Like an input view (and you already done it). I modified you code. You can just compare and check what was wrong there

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var freq: UILabel!
    var freqOptions = ["Hz", "kHz", "MHz"]
    var freqPicker = UIPickerView()
    @IBOutlet weak var freqTextField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        freqPicker = UIPickerView()
        freqPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        freqPicker.delegate = self
        freqPicker.dataSource = self
//        freqPicker.isHidden = true
        let toolBar    = UIToolbar()
        let cancelItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Cancel",
            style: .plain,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(cancelFreqInput)
        )
        let middleItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let doneItem   = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Done",
            style: .done,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(confirmFreqInput)
        )
        toolBar.setItems( [cancelItem, middleItem, doneItem], animated : false )
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
//        view.addSubview(freqPicker)
        let freqTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(freqTap(gestureReconizer:)))
        freq.addGestureRecognizer(freqTap)
        freqTextField.inputView = freqPicker
        freqTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        freqTextField.isHidden = true
        freq.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        freqPicker.reloadComponent(0)
    }
    
    @objc func cancelFreqInput() {
        freqTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        freq.text = "Hz"
        freqTextField.isHidden = true
    }
    
    @objc func confirmFreqInput() {
        freq.text = freqOptions[freqPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return freqOptions.count
    }
    
//    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
//        freq.text = freqOptions[row]
//        self.view.endEditing(true)
//    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return freqOptions[row]
    }

    @objc func freqTap(gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        freqTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alex. This works great for click events in the UITextField object, but I want to capture a click gesture on the ```freq: UILabel!``` object. Is this possible?

Comment: You can just style you textField as UILabel and it will be ready for you, or not? :-) Looks like a trick, but anyway - it is what are you whant

Comment: Also you can hide UITextField and after click on UILabel just open a UITextField. It is okay for you? I can modify the code

Comment: I updated the code, and now it works as you want by click on UILabel

Comment: This is close. But, I don't want the UILabel value to change until "done" is clicked. If I add ```freq.text = freqOptions[ freqPicker.selectedRow(inComponent : 0) ]``` to ```@objc func confirmFreqInput() {}``` and remove ```func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {}``` entirely, then I get my desired behavior. Thanks! Can you update and then I'll accept? I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Check it now, please! Looks like it is what you want

Comment: Yup, perfect! I'll edit the question to include the details in these comments.